# How can I get my PC to boot again?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, drivers, bsod, system-recovery

I am no longer able to boot my PC and get a blue screen saying "The digital signature for this file couldn't be verified", along with error code 0xc0000428.

I have tried booting to a USB device in order to access the recovery tools and have tried:

1. Running Startup Repair
2. Running bootrec /fixMBR and /fixBoot in the command prompt which were both completed successfully
3. Running /rebuildBCD in the command prompt which said:

   *Total identified Windows installations: 1
   [1] C:\Windows
   Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A)*

   I entered "Y" and the the following message appeared:

   *The requested system device cannot be found*

However the system still shows the same blue screen. I don't think there are any major issues with the hard drive as I was able to back my files up onto to an external device.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do next? Are there any more command prompt tests I can try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try method 3 on [this list](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-error-code-0xc0000428-bsod-on-windows/) and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried disabling driver signature enforcement?

Comment: @Myles is there a way of doing this with command prompt? Because in the 'Advanced options' section of the 'Troubleshoot' menu I don't have the 'Startup Settings' option. I only have 'System Restore', 'Command Prompt', 'System Image Recovery', 'Go back to the previous version', and 'Startup Repair'. I tried 'Startup Repair' but I got a message saying 'Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC'...

Comment: @DrZoo unfortunately I'm not shown 'Startup Settings' within 'Advanced options'

Comment: @Myles just an update - I have tried disabling driver signature enforcement using the command bcdedit /set testsigning on, but I get "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found". Any other suggestions?